# Next.js 13 with Prisma: Database entries not updating in production

Tags: next.js, prisma, next.js13

I have a Next.js 13 application integrated with Prisma, connecting to a MySQL database. Everything works perfectly locally. However, in production, when I add new entries, they don't reflect in the UI or even in the API response. This seems like a caching issue, since the updates only appear after every deployment. I've tried various caching headers (force-cache, no-cache, etc.) without success.

Here's my API route for fetching the entries:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const guestbookEntries = await prisma.entries.findMany();
    return Response.json(guestbookEntries);
  } catch (error) {
    return Response.json({
      error: 'Error getting guestbook entries',
    });
  }
}
```

And here's the function for getting the entries:

```
const getGuestbookEntries = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/getGuestbookEntries', {
      cache: 'force-cache',
    });
    const entries = await response.json();
    setData(entries);
  } catch (err) {
    setErrorMessage('Error on fetching');
    setSeverity('error');
    setIsVisible(true);
  }
};
```